# php anonymous function throw Error on php 5.2

Tags: php, function, anonymous-function

I have the following code.

```
$resu = array_map(function($aVal, $bVal){
return "$bVal [$aVal]";
}, $result, $intersect);

$sorAr = array();
array_walk($resu, function($element) use (&$sorAr) {
$parts = explode(" ", $element);
$sorAr[$parts[0]] = trim($parts[1], ' []');
});
```

The problem lies when i need to use the anonymous function in both variable $resu and on array_walk. the error shows as follows

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /dir...

I try to read on this site different suggestion but no luck. how do i solve this problem. Some one help please?

I have tried this code...

```
function arrSwap() { 
                        $arraySwap = function($aVal, $bVal){
                            return "$bVal [$aVal]";
                            };                         
                        $resu = array_map($arraySwap, $result, $intersect);
                        }

                        $sorAr = array();
                        function arrSwap2() {
                        $arrayWalk = function($element) use (&$sorAr) {
                            $parts = explode(" ", $element);
                            $sorAr[$parts[0]] = trim($parts[1], ' []');
                        }; 
                        array_walk($resu, $arrayWalk);
                        }
```

but i get this error...

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare arrSwap() (previously declared in  on line 100...
which the line 100 is this -> function arrSwap() {

Comment: check your php version and see for anonymous functions are supported for that version or not ?

Comment: unfortunately it is not supported, 5.2.6. how do i re-write the above code to work on this version?

Comment: yes, there are two options one is to update the php version for above or change the function, although if this prob. is occurring at time of hosting then just raise a ticket to server support team to update the servers php version .

Comment: ya, that is what my real question here is, how do i change the above code to work on lower version on php like < 5.3?

Comment: create two separate functions for these anonymous functions suppose on is having name fn1 having signature as of function($aVal, $bVal) and then pass the argument by separating comma by calling like  array_map(fn1, $result, $intersect); and same thing have have to be applied for second anonymous function also

Comment: could you please write it down as a code please???

Comment: try below snippet of code -- function arr1($aVal, $bVal){
                            return "$bVal [$aVal]";
        }
function arrayWalk($element){
       $parts = explode(" ", $element);
      $sorAr[$parts[0]] = trim($parts[1], ' []');
    }
    
function arrSwap(){
    $resu = array_map('arr1', $result, $intersect);
    $sorAr = array();
    array_walk($resu, 'arrayWalk');
} , if still prob there let me know all these values being passed there.

Answer (score 4):

Anonymous functions are **not** available in **5.2**

See the changelog [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

> **5.3.0**  Anonymous functions become available.

Answer (score 0):

```
function arr1($aVal, $bVal){ return "$bVal [$aVal]"; } 
function arrayWalk($element){ $parts = explode(" ", $element); $sorAr[$parts[0]] = trim($parts[1], ' []'); } 
function arrSwap(){ $resu = array_map('arr1', $result, $intersect); $sorAr = array(); array_walk($resu, 'arrayWalk'); }
```

if still prob there let me know all these values being passed there

Comment: still i am getting the same problem, I am calling the function inside the foreach loop, does this has some thing to do with the error?

Comment: which one function is being called in foreach loop , although calling a function in foreach loop have not to change it's behaviour , debug your code by checking the array data and other variables being passed inside the function that is only the way you can get the solution just by tracing them on each step.